# Avoid NTLM authentication method

Tags: vb.net, security, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have a web application which is developed using vb.net.
My web application uses Windows authentication mode.

Security team scanned the application and reported one issue.

**Steps followed to produce the issue:**

```
1. Type the url in browser (url - https://sample/applicationname) and press Enter

2. Analyze the response using proxy tool 'Fiddler' - which shows that authentication method in NTLM which is insecure.
```

**Recomendations given by security team:**

```
Change authentication method to a more secure one such as Digest, client certificates or similar. Otherwise use an encrypted channel to protect information by implementing HTTPS.
```

Note: HTTPS is already implemented.

Kindly let me know how to solve the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with NTLM?  And if you're already using HTTPS then you already meet the stated requirements.  At any rate, changing the authentication protocols is up to the server administrator, not to the programmer, so I think you'd have better luck on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digest is less secure than NTLM, so you may want to mock your security team. Digest uses MD5 (in a weak manner) and requires reversible passwords. If you really want to go more secure than NTLM, your may want to configure kerberos.  The options vary depending on your version of IIS.  Google will have your answer.

Comment: Digest is less secure than NTLM means.. is it better to go with Client Certification Authentication. Please give me ref link to check how to configure both IIS and my Web.config file for client certification authentication.